# DataStudio Google Analytics Connector Showing Zeros for Some Metrics

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I have a google analytics report in datastudio. One of the pages in the report is attempting to report on events. In GA when looking at the event in the e-commerce explorer tab I will see data for revenue, ecommerce conversion rate, per session value, but in my data studio report all values show as zero.

This is a straight google analytics data source (i.e. there is no data blending).

Screen shots below of the datastudio result and the analytics report for the data I am trying to match.

Every resource I can find says this should be possible and the fact that Google Analytics has the exact same data showing again makes me think this is possible.

Is there an issue with what I am doing or the metrics / dimensions I am calling? If not why isn't this working?

[image: Datastudio]

[image: Analytics Report]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with something like this too. I would guess that the problem is with the decimal places, which I couldn't get to work in GDS - zeroes all over the place, just like you are getting. When I multiplied the defined event value by 100, it all worked. Worth a try, I think.